# Should I do data insert for a model inside the controller or inside the model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

As my question title states I would like to know all the best practices and pros/cons of following the "Laravel way" of inserting the data in the db.

Is it a bad practice using the `Model::create([...])` for inserting a new row in the database which is related to that controller's model?

Is creating a separate function inside the model itself a much better practice?

If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on size of your project you can use your models directly in your controller and use the fluent interface of Eloquent to do your logic.

There is nothing wrong that you call a model in a controller to get data from database.

If there is some complicated query you can create method in your model and than call that method in controller ...

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can use insert in controller , view(blade) or even in route . 
But recommended is on your controller. This help to make your code clean

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look for [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers). It has already predefined logic like `store()` method where you can put some `Model::create()`, as you said.

That's not bad if you also create a method inside model and call it from your controller.

I think, that `create()` method for straght storing some data from request (from some form on front-end, as an example) is enough. But if you want/need to make more than straight storing model, a separate method inside model might take place. Apart to avoid controller's method overgrowth and keep your code pretty.

The answer really *depends on*, so maybe you will shed some light on the logic you want to implement.

Comment: hi, thanks! my question was simply due to the fact that I'm creating an API and I have followed the code samples that laravel provides, although if we think about the MVC pattern I thought that everything that is related to the model and data should be handles in the models... (? )

Comment: For API caase you can use your own API transformation layer. Like app/Http/Api/ - and place some classes there which might handle your api data